# Is there a way to use a string from a list as the label for an array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, label

I have data that has been given to me as a list in this format:

```
['NAME', 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0, 28.0]
```

What I want to do is to convert it to an array with this format:

```
NAME=[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0, 28.0]
```

Is there a way to do this with code or am I better off manually labeling some the arrays and appending data to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a dictionary:

```
# suppose that l is your list

my_data = {l[0]: l[1:]}
```

later in code, you can use:

```
my_data['NAME']
```

Comment: Will this allow me to call the array later in the code e.g. if L[1:] = NAME i could use print(NAME) and it would print the array?